# What type of if function code should I use?

Tags: flutter, dart

There are two types of `if` function codes:

```
if (condition1) {
  function1
}
if (condition2) {
  function2
}
function3
```

---

```
if (condition2) {
  function1
} else {
  if (condition3) {
    function2
  } else {
    function3
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the correct way to use the `if` function code, I hope everyone can tell me.

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

What type of `if` function code should I use? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else` only runs when the `if` is not true. What you need to use depends on what you want it to do.

In your first example, if both `condition1` and `condition2` are true then both `function1` and `function2` will run. `function3` will run regardless of the conditions.

In your second example when `condition2` and `condition3` are true, only `function1` will run because it will never go in the `else` block. So `function3` will only run when both `condition2` and `condition3` are false, and `function2` will only run when `condition2` is false and `condition3` is true.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Ok, now I know. I think my question is wrongly interpreted, I will ask another question